# Extending a Java collection class like ArrayList for easier Generics management (warnings...etc)?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Extending Java default collections is not considered good practice. 
But i am wondering if, for the sake of cleaner code, one would not extend, say ArrayList to get rid of the generic. For example

```
public class DoodleList extends ArrayList<Doodle> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

So that in one's code you do some thing like "someFramework.getContentAs(DoodleList.class)" without having those nasty warnings about generics...etc

**NOTE**
Wrapping the List might not be an option in my case : the class is to be used in JSON mapping where the desired output is :

{doodles : [doodle1,doodle2,doodle3]}

not {doodles : {innerCollection : [doodle1,doodle2,doodle3]}}

Comment: Who ever said that extending a collection were a bad practice?

Comment: Rather than extending it, I'd wrap it. Not that it seems useful or cleaner, after all it is a matter of taste.

Comment: Ooh, me!  I'd say extending collections is a bad practice!

Comment: @LouisWasserman Never heard about that. Could you briefly explain me why?

Comment: Effective Java item 16, "Favor composition over inheritance," explains it better than I could.  I'd be absolutely 100% for making the `java.util` collection implementations `final`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it says "favor composition over inheritance" not "use composition over inheritance exclusively."

Comment: Sure, but I've never once seen a case where composition couldn't be used instead of inheritance for collection types.

Comment: @emory `Stack` decided to extend `Vector`, and that killed its career.

Comment: There's no need to prefix questions with tags, there's a tag system for that purpose. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information

Comment: Normally that's what i'd do, wrap the collection. But this same class is to be used in some json/jackson mapping and wrapping would make it output something like {doodles:{innerCollection:[,,,]}} whereas the desired output is {doodles:[,,,]}

Comment: @redben That last comment of yours is important for the context of the question. You should've added it from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding nasty warnings by playing around with inheritance smells to me.

Why not just use the annotation to suppress the warning. For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
someFramework.getContentAs(ArrayList.class)"
```

Comment: Your approach is to hide (or suppress) the nasty warning.  The OP is not hiding anything.  If I understand the OP correctly, this approach is solving the underlying problem, thus no warning.

Comment: @emory I do this all the time with `JPanel`'s and the like.

Comment: Right, but that's exactly what i don't want in my code (@SuppressWarnings everywhere) :)

Comment: That's the price of reflection, I'm afraid.

Comment: Indeed - this is a warning from the compiler and it needs to be suppressed. Hacking the Collections API to suppress the warning is really not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to get rid of the warnings use `SuppressWarnings`.

However if `DoodleList` contains more than just a `ArrayList<Doodle>` e.g. implements Doodle-specific logic, I see no problem extending `ArrayList<Doodle>`.